# $50$ people sit around a round table . We want to choose $5$ people among them so that there are at least four people between any two selected people.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> $50$ people sit around a round table and eat dinner. We want to choose $5$ people among them to serve extra dessert such that there are at least $4$ people between any two of the selected people. How many ways are there to select these $5$ people?

**My thoughts :** Cut the table randomly somewhere to make a line. After that, assume that there are $45$ blue and $5$ red balls. We disperse them to people so that the people who took red balls will be selected.

Assume that we lined up the four red balls and want to distribute the blues by obeying the given restrictions. Then, we can do it by $$\binom{24}{4}$$
because if there must be at least $4$ people among the selected ones, there must be at least $4$ blue balls among the red balls, but realize that the sum of the left side of first red and the right side of the fifth red must be at least $4$ reds, because it is actually a circle.

However, my answer is wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: Is this the **exact** wording of the question ? If not, please furnish the exact wording.

Comment: @trueblueanil yes it is the question

Comment: There must be a language barrier issue or translation error here... I agree, this makes no sense.  "We want to choose 5 people... such that there are at least 4 people among them"  Any way of choosing five people is such that there are at least four (in fact there are five because that is the number we picked) among those five people...

Comment: @KarlW. I believe that the question should state that “there should be at least 4 people between any two consecutive selected people”, instead of “ there are at least 4 people among the selected people”. If you agree, then please edit the question. I’m not editing because I don’t know the author’s intention.

Comment: @KarlW. now the edit is perfectly crystal clear; do you still not see the problem with the question statement? Of not, I suggest you reread it and compare it to the edit.

Comment: Your approach is not clear.  Are you trying to solve the equation $x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 45$ subject to the restrictions that $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \geq 4$ and $x_0 + x_5 \geq 4$, where $x_0$ is the number of blue balls to the left of the first red ball, $x_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$, is the number of blue balls between the $i$th red ball and the $(i + 1)$st red ball, and $x_5$ is the number of blue balls to the right of the fifth red ball?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yeah what yu wrote

Comment: @N.F.Taussig do you have any suggestion for my question ?

Comment: @KarlW.  I interpreted the problem to mean that we are selecting five people from a round table containing $50$ people and that there must be at least four people between any two of the selected people.  I obtained the same answer as true blue anil by implementing the method I mentioned in the comments above.  If I have interpreted the problem incorrectly, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Going by your interpretation of at least $4$ people **between each** of the selected $5$,

- make $5$ blocks of $\;\;\boxed{SNNNN}\;\;$ ($S$ = selected, $N$ = not selected)
- arrange the $5$ blocks in $\;25 +5\;$ *entities* in $\;\binom{30}5$ ways
- multiply by $\frac{50}{30}$ as  each $S$ is getting only $30$ starting places instead of $50$
- final answer $= \frac{50}{30}\binom{30}5 = 237,510$

Comment: thanks but not mathcing with answer key

Comment: @N. F. Taussig: **1:** Does your method give a different answer ? **2.** Btw, I remember that once, while recommending books for beginners, you had mentioned a book on combinatorics solving whose questions were almost addictive. A friend was asking about it, I couldn't trace it. Can you give the link, or the book's name ? Regards.

Comment: I apologize for the slow response (I've been watching the World Athletics Championships).  I also obtained $237,510$ by interpreting the problem to mean that we select five people at a round table so that there are at least four people between any two of the selected people.  The book that originally sparked my interest in combinatorics was Ivan Niven's *Mathematics of Choice*, which is a basic introduction to the subject.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig: No sweat, thanks for the reference ! Idk what the question means, because what is purported to be the exact question is meaningless !

Comment: This is an elegant solution to the problem described in the edit.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig:Glad that you like it, thanks. ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: @trueblueanil I think you must elaborately explain the part of multiplying by $(50/30)$

Answer (score 0):

We will solve this problem for a row, then subtract those cases in which joining the ends of the row leaves fewer than four people between two of the selected people.

Line up the $50$ people in a row.  Let $x_0$ be the number of people to the left of the first selected person; let $x_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$, be the number of people between the $i$th selected person and the $(i + 1)$st selected person; let $x_5$ be the number of people to the right of the fifth selected person.  Since five of the $50$ people are selected, $50 - 5 = 45$ are not.  Hence,
$$x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 45 \tag{1}$$
Since at least four people must be between any two selected people, $x_i \geq 4$ for $1 \leq i \leq 4$.  Ignoring the restrictions associated joining with the ends of the line for now, $x_0, x_5 \geq 0$.  If we set $x_i' = x_i - 4$ for $1 \leq i \leq 4$, then each such $x_i'$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_i' + 4$ for $x_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$ yields
\begin{align*}
x_0 + x_1' + 4 + x_2' + 4 + x_3' + 4 + x_4' + 4 + x_5 & = 45\\
x_0 + x_1' + x_2' + x_3' + x_4' + x_5 & = 29 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers.

A particular solution of the equation corresponds to the placement of $6 - 1 = 5$ addition signs in a row of $29$ ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_0 = 6, x_1' = 7, x_2' = 0, x_3' = 5, x_4' = 9, x_5 = 2$ of equation $2$ (and $x_0 = 6, x_1 = 11, x_2 = 4, x_3 = 9, x_4 = 13, x_5 = 2$ of equation $1$).  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can select which five of the $34$ positions required for $29$ ones and five addition signs will be filled with addition signs, which is
$$\binom{29 + 6 - 1}{6 - 1} = \binom{34}{5}$$
This is the number of ways five people could be selected from $50$ people lined up in a row if there are at least four people between any two of the selected people.

For a circle, we must impose the additional restriction that $x_0 + x_5 \geq 4$ so that there are at least four people between any two of the selected people after we join the ends of the row to form a circle.  Therefore, we must subtract those cases in which $x_0 + x_5 \leq 3$.

$x_0 + x_5 = 0$:  The equation $x_0 + x_5 = 0$ has one solution in the nonnegative integers.  Substituting $0$ for $x_0 + x_5$ in equation $1$ yields
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 45$$
Substituting $x_i' + 4$ for $x_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$, in the preceding equation and simplifying yields
$$x_1' + x_2' + x_3' + x_4' = 29$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{29 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{32}{3}$$
solutions.

$x_0 + x_5 = 1$:  The equation $x_0 + x_5 = 1$ has two solutions in the nonnegative integers.  If $x_0 + x_5 = 1$, then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 44$$
and
$$x_1' + x_2' + x_3' + x_4' = 28$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{28 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{31}{3}$$
solutions.  Hence, there are
$$2\binom{31}{3}$$
such cases.

$x_0 + x_5 = 2$:  The equation $x_0 + x_5 = 2$ has three solutions in the nonnegative integers.  If $x_0 + x_5 = 2$, then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 43$$
and
$$x_1' + x_2' + x_3' + x_4' = 27$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{27 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{30}{3}$$
solutions.  Hence, there are
$$3\binom{30}{3}$$
such cases.

$x_0 + x_5 = 3$:  The equation $x_0 + x_5 = 3$ has four solutions in the nonnegative integers.  If $x_0 + x_5 = 3$, then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 42$$
and
$$x_1' + x_2' + x_3' + x_4' = 26$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{26 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{29}{3}$$
solutions.  Hence, there are
$$4\binom{29}{3}$$
such cases.

Thus, the number of ways we can select five people from a round table at which $50$ people are seated so that at least four people are seated between any two of the selected people is
$$\binom{34}{5} - \binom{32}{3} - 2\binom{31}{3} - 3\binom{30}{3} - 4\binom{29}{3} = 237,510$$
in agreement with the answer true blue anil obtained through an elegant symmetry argument.

Answer (score -1):

Since you must have at least 4 people between 2 people you can treat 1 selected person and the next 4 people as a single selected person and simplify the initial problem by subtracting all the 4 non selected people next to each selected person to the initial 50 people, so this problem should be the same as how many ways are there to select 5 people among 30 people. The answer should be:
$$
\binom{30}{5}=142506
$$

Comment: wrong answer buddy

Comment: Your solution is wrong because it misses cases in which a selected person is in the last four seats.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification