There are 20 points on a circle and 4 random points are selected then the probability that there are at least 2 points in between any 2 selected point
There are 20 points on a circle and 4 random points are selected then the probability that there are at least two points in between any two selected point

Find out conditions when 2 points are never in between any two selected points

Are all the points on the Circle distinct?

Yes all points are distinct

This question seems similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4495245/50-people-sit-around-a-round-table-we-want-to-choose-5-people-among-them-s?rq=1

Hint: By the circular symmetry, we can assume without loss of generality that point #1 is selected. Selecting the remaining 3 points corresponds to choosing a valid sequence of gap sizes. Count the ways of doing this, with and without the minimum gap size requirement.
